# How do create a Batch file to add "END" to last row of .csv file

Tags: batch

I have a process that runs daily to pull retail transactions from our POS system that it outputs as a .csv file. we then send the file over to our accounting department where they manipulate the data to be imported into another system. They have asked if I can add the word "END" after the last transaction line so they can use scripting to determine if all the contents of the file were imported correctly

I would like to be able use a batch file to append the existing file without creating a copy of it as our file names are specific to each date they are created

here is the sample data. with it being a .csv file, I would assume an additional row would need to be added to the end?

```
DATASET|HOST|HOSTSERVER|LOCATION|PERIOD|REGISTERNUMBER|CASHIERUSERNAME|SESSIONID|SESSIONSTARTDATETIME|SESSIONENDDATETIME|TRANSACTIONID|TRANSACTIONNUMBER|TRANSACTIONDATETIME|TRANSACTIONDATE|DATEKEY|TRANSACTIONTIMEINSECONDS|TRANSACTIONTYPE|FIRSTPAYMENTTYPE|FIRSTPAYMENTAMOUNT|FIRSTPAYMENTCARDTYPE|FIRSTPAYMENTACCOUNT|FIRSTPAYMENTACCOUNTNUMBER|FIRSTPAYMENTEMPLOYEEID|FIRSTPAYMENTCHARGEACCOUNTGROUP|SECONDPAYMENTTYPE|SECONDPAYMENTAMOUNT|SECONDPAYMENTCARDTYPE|SECONDPAYMENTACCOUNT|SECONDPAYMENTACCOUNTNUMBER|SECONDPAYMENTEMPLOYEEID|SECONDPAYMENTCHARGEACCOUNTGROUP|DISCOUNTPERCENTAGE|DISCOUNTDESCRIPTION|DISCOUNTAMOUNT|SURCHARGEPERCENTAGE|SURCHARGEDESCRIPTION|SURCHARGEAMOUNT|COUPONUSEDAMOUNT|COUPONAMOUNT|COUPONDISCAMOUNT|COUPONDESCRIPTION|VOIDAMOUNT|REWARDDESCRIPTION|REWARDAMOUNT|TAXAMOUNT|TAXDIFF|GROSSSALESCOUNT|GROSSSALESAMOUNT
IHC_TST|HSADMIN|LPV-COMPTDEV01.CO.IHC.COM|Master|Breakfast|2|ldbevans|48|2022-01-21 08:21:00|2022-01-21 11:46:27|92|000100002220121082100|2022-01-21 08:21:00|2022-01-21|20220121|32|Void||0|||||||0||||||||0|||0|0|0|0||11.13||0|0|0|0|0
IHC_TST|HSADMIN|LPV-COMPTDEV01.CO.IHC.COM|Master|Breakfast|2|ldbevans|48|2022-01-21 08:21:00|2022-01-21 11:46:27|93|000100002220121085529|2022-01-21 08:55:29|2022-01-21|20220121|17|Void||0|||||||0||||||||0|||0|0|0|0||16.07||0|0|0|0|0
IHC_TST|HSADMIN|LPV-COMPTDEV01.CO.IHC.COM|Master|Breakfast|2|ldbevans|48|2022-01-21 08:21:00|2022-01-21 11:46:27|94|000100002220121091317|2022-01-21 09:13:17|2022-01-21|20220121|48|Void||0|||||||0||||||||0|||0|0|0|0||0.99||0|0|0|0|0
IHC_TST|HSADMIN|LPV-COMPTDEV01.CO.IHC.COM|Master|Lunch|2|ldbevans|49|2022-01-21 11:47:26|2022-01-21 11:47:26|95|000100002220121114726|2022-01-21 11:47:26|2022-01-21|20220121|36|Sale Cash|Cash|0|||||||0||||||||0|||0|5.98|7|0|PrePaid Voucher $7|0||0|0|0|1|5.98
```

I am running this process on an Windows 2016 server

Comment: If you have a .csv file which only has the word "END" in it, you can do `type file1.csv file2.csv > concat.csv`. Take it from there and DO YOUR RESEARCH. Then come back if sth doesn't work. This Forum is NOT a script writing service.

Comment: @Brandon: _A comma-separated values (CSV) file is a delimited text file that uses a comma to separate values. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas._ Just wondering: **Why There is no any comma(s) in your csv file?**

Comment: @Brandon, you can use different delimiters, like | or ;

Comment: Your accounting department is going to have to be more specific. Just adding 'END' to the file will break its format and can lead to problems importing it. You could add a pre-specified formatted line with END in it, but how are accounting thinking they will process it ? Also, how is specifying END going to tell them how many records should have been imported ?

Comment: just to expand: the last row might contain `END|` plus however many delimiters with no data so that it conforms to the delimited format. This would yield a record with field("dataset") value("END") and all others null/undefined/default.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

In command line:

```bat
> for /f usebackqˆdelimsˆ= %i in (`type .\"your_file.csv"`)do @echo.%~iˆ|END>>.\"your_file_END.csv"

> move /y .\"your_file_END.csv" .\"your_file.csv"
```

---

In batch file:

```bat
@echo off 

for /f usebackqˆdelimsˆ= %%i in (`type .\"your_file.csv"
    `)do echo.%%~iˆ|END>>.\"your_file_END.csv"

move /y .\"your_file_END.csv" .\"your_file.csv"
```

---

If you need to skip the header:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f usebackqˆdelimsˆ= %%i in (`type .\"file.csv"
    `)do echo."%%~i"|findstr/b ".DATASET" >nul && (
            echo.%%~i>>.\"your_file_END.csv" ) || (
            echo.%%~iˆ|END>>.\"your_file_END.csv" )

move /y .\"your_file_END.csv" .\"your_file.csv"

endlocal
```